# Positioning a Button on the right TKINTER

Tags: python, button, tkinter

How do I make a button stay on the right side of the GUI? I tried sticky but it seems to not work on buttons? Or am I doing something wrong? The button at the bottom of the GUI that says "Start" is on the right, but not fully sticking towards the right.

This is the code:
from tkinter import *

```
class MathQuiz:
def __init__(self, parent):
    #Variables
    self.question_number = -1
    self.question_limit = 10
    self.score = 0
    self.user_name = ""

    #Title frame on every page
    self.title_frame = Frame(parent, bg = "#2F2F97")
    self.title_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
    #Title label on every page
    self.title_label = Label(self.title_frame, text = "Math Quiz", bg = "#2F2F97", fg = "#ffffff", font = ("Trebuchet MS", 30)) 
    self.title_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    #Intro Frame creation
    self.intro_frame =Frame(parent)
    self.intro_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    #Label description about program
    self.description_label = Label(self.intro_frame, justify = "left", text = "This programme will help children from age 8 to 12 with their math. The\nquiz consists of {} questions which vary based on the difficulty selected. \n\nEasy: Addition \nMedium: Addition and Subtraction \nHard: Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication".format(self.question_limit))
    self.description_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, columnspan = 2)

    #Label guidance to tell user what to do
    self.input_directions = Label(self.intro_frame, text = "Please enter your name and age:")
    self.input_directions.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = W)

    #Creating entries for the user to input Name
    self.name_direction = Label(self.intro_frame, text = "Name:")
    self.name_direction.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = W)
    self.answer_entry = Entry(self.intro_frame)
    self.answer_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = E)
    self.answer_entry.focus()
    #Allows the use of 'Enter' key instead of clicking self.next_button
    self.answer_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda _: self.Next())

    #Creating entries for the user to input Age
    self.age_direction =Label(self.intro_frame, text = "Age:")
    self.age_direction.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = W)
    self.age_entry = Entry(self.intro_frame)
    self.age_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = E)
    self.age_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda _: self.Next())

    #Creating a label to give user feedback
    self.feedback_label = Label(self.intro_frame, text = "")
    self.feedback_label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    #Finish Frame creation
    self.finish_frame = Frame(parent)
    self.bot_finish_frame = Frame(self.finish_frame, bg = "#8B4513")
    self.new_user_button = Button(self.bot_finish_frame, text = "Next User", width = 15, bg = "#8B4513", fg = "#ffffff", activebackground = "#2F2F97", activeforeground = "#CFCFCF", font = ("Trebuchet MS", 15))

    #Result Frame creation
    self.results_frame = Frame(parent)
    self.bot_results_frame = Frame(self.results_frame, bg = "#8B4513")

    #Setting up difficulty choices
    self.bot = Frame(self.intro_frame, bg = "#8B4513")
    self.bot.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = EW)
    self.difficulty_frame = Frame(self.bot, bg = "#8B4513")
    self.difficulty_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = EW)
    self.difficulty_list = ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"]
    self.difficulty_value = StringVar()
    self.difficulty_value.set(-1)

    for i in range(0,len(self.difficulty_list)):
        self.difficulty_rb = Radiobutton(self.difficulty_frame, text = self.difficulty_list[i], fg = "#ffffff", bg = "#8B4513", selectcolor = "#8B4513", activeforeground = "#CFCFCF", activebackground = "#8B4513", variable = self.difficulty_value, value = self.difficulty_list[i])
        self.difficulty_rb.grid(row = 0, column = i, stick = EW, padx = 20, pady = 10)
        self.difficulty_rb.bind("<Return>", lambda _: self.Next())

    self.next_button = Button(self.bot, text = "Start", width = 15, bg = "#8B4513", fg = "#ffffff", activebackground = "#2F2F97", activeforeground = "#CFCFCF", font = ("Trebuchet MS", 15))
    self.next_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = E)

root = Tk()
root.option_add("*Font", "arial 15")
root.tk_setPalette(background = "#F6F9FF")
window = MathQuiz(root)
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, for some reason the indentation changed when i transferred the code here. I fixed the indentation already.

Comment: It is still wrong. Look at the `for` statement.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, sorry, stupid mistake. But how do get the sticky = E to work in the last line of the code for self.next_button?

Comment: When I run your code the next button is on the right side of its parent. Perhaps you're asking how to make its parent expand to the right? There's simply not enough context to know what the solution is. Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BryanOakley Hmm I didn't realise that this section of code on its own would work as I intended it to, because in my full code, the button is not fully sticking to the right, there is a slight gap, bigger than the gap i set for padx. I edited the code and checked it now and it is displaying the same error as my actual code.